# What is the term for the wool like stuff that secretes between the newborn's fingers?

Tags: newborn, health

So, we have been noticing a wool like stuff in between the finger gaps of our newborn (2.5 months age) for past many days. We clean it daily and it keeps on reappearing.

Doctor told us not to worry since it is normal for a newborn to secrete this stuff.

What is the technical term for this?

Comment: given the answer, if your doctor told you "not to worry about these kind of secretions" then I'd suggest the doctor isn't paying much attention to the situation, and may put your baby at risk.  I encourage you to tell them this directly if you decide to switch.

Comment: @NewAlexandria, it's possible that the Dr said "don't worry about it, it's just a result of the natural secretions": meaning that clothing lint sticks to skin secretions, not that the lint itself is a skin secretion - but the author understood the Dr's statement the other way.

Comment: @Vicky Actually we thought it to be a fungus of some sort. The doc said that it is not fungus, it gets secreted from the baby's body on its own.

Comment: @user462608 it sounds like you're saying the doc said the lint was (itself) a secretion.  If so, I urge you with all my sincerity, go now and find a doctor that given a sh*t.  *This one does not*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not secreted by the baby.

It's just clothes fluff / lint getting caught between their fingers (their fingers being quite sticky with normal skin secretions), and they're not using their hands or washing them like we do which would normally wipe the clothing fluff off with it.

See eg

- http://baby.about.com/od/Newborn-Hands-And-Feet/tp/Newborn-Fingers-And-Toes.htm
- http://blogs.babycenter.com/mom_stories/why-are-infant-hands-lint-traps/